# delete if password is correct

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

i need to create a condition that clears the record but with a password.

if the password is correct execute the **delete();**

controller:

```
      public function eliminar($id){

    $registros = \App\Models\Registro::findOrFail($id);
    $registros->delete();
     
    return redirect('sistema')->with('mensaje', 'Registro Borrado con exito');
}

    public function borrar($id){
        // return $request->all();
        $data = [
            'category_name' => 'datatable',
            'page_name' => 'multiple_tables',
        'has_scrollspy' => 0,
        'scrollspy_offset' => '',
        'fechax' => Carbon::now(),
        'borrar' => \App\Models\Registro::findOrFail($id),
        'password' => 'PASSCODE',
      

        ];
       
    

        return view('borrar')->with($data);
    }
```

blade.php:

```
  <h1>Do you want to delete the record?</h1>



<form action="{{ route('eliminar', $borrar) }}" class="d-inline" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">DELETE</button>


    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label for="telefono">Password</label>
                                                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="telefono"  required>
                                            </div>
</form>
```

the password is obtained statically

How can I make it delete without the password is identical?

help please

Comment: By password, you mean the authenticated user's password?

Comment: No, a static password. defined in a variable.
The password would work as a code to remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the password is saved statically, inside in a variable, the following should do the job for you.

routes/web.php

```
Route::delete('/path/here', 'SomeController@destroy');
```

SomeController.php

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $model = YourModel::find($id);
    if (! $model) {
        session()->flash('error_message', 'Model not found with the given id: ', . $id);
        return back();
    }

    // $password is the password that you have saved somewhere
    if (request()->password_field_value == $password) {
        $model->delete();

        session()->flash('success_message', 'Model deleted successfully.');
        return back();
    }

    session()->flash('error_message', 'Invalid password. Try again');
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Can I save a static password like this ?: $ password = ['PASS'];

Comment: @jererosas If you store `$password = ['PASS']`, it would be considered an array. You can use it that way as well, but you will have to update the condition of checking the `$password`. It should be `$password[0]`. I would suggest don't go for array since there is only 1 value in it.